# getting error while installing the yarn in react js project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

```
$ yarn install
yarn install v1.19.1
warning package-lock.json found. Your project contains lock files generated by tools other than Yarn. It is advised not to mix package managers in order to avoid resolution inconsistencies cau
sed by unsynchronized lock files. To clear this warning, remove package-lock.json.
[1/5] Validating package.json...
error app@0.3.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.17.0". Got "10.15.2"
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

getting the errors while installing the yarn in react js project

```
error app@0.3.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=10.17.0". Got "10.15.2"
error Found incompatible module.
```

Comment: remove `package-lock.json` or use `npm install`

Comment: about the second error: add file `.node-version` in the root which include single line: `v10.17.0`. But first you need to install the same node version on your local machine.

Comment: @demkovych I would to like install yarn in a project.

Comment: then remove `package-lock.json` and run `yarn install --ignore-engines`

Comment: @demkovych thanks man this is working. can you please add the answer then I can vote your answer thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `package-lock.json` and run `yarn install --ignore-engines`

Answer (score 0):

When working on a team, sometimes another dev installs it. One good way to avoid this happening is using [package-locks-checks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/package-locks-checks), which I wrote.

If you run `npx package-locks-checks` it will check for this kind of inconsistencies and avoid you to have issues on production environment.

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.